# Using validators inside callback validator of Entity

Tags: symfony

How do I access and use validators inside an Entity?

A little detail on what I'm trying to do:

I have a User Entity and want to create a validation rule that says: If Users hair color is set and is valid, eye color is not mandatory, else eye color is mandatory.

So in my validation.yml I've set a callback validator and indicated that I want to call a funciton: isHairOrEyeValid(). This funciton is defined in the User entity. I need to use some of the symfony2 built in validators inside the isHairOrEyeValid() function of the User Entity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use most validators by instantiating them inline:

```
$validator = new EmailValidator();
$valid = $validator->isValid($email, new Email());
```

In your case, it looks like you can accomplish this validation with simple PHP. I'm not sure why you want to involve validators.